# Custom plugin: asset fieldtype

Tags: plugin-development, assets, craft3, custom-fieldtype

I have a custom plugin that uses a custom field leveraging the `elementSelect` fieldtype to select an asset (which is then processed on submission via a custom service). However, when I select an asset via my field, I get the following JS error in console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-id="["1286"]"]:first
```

The integer above relates to the selected asset.

Has anyone come across this issue before?
It was working previously so not sure if a Craft update has broken it.

The plugin field template:

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}
{{ forms.elementSelectField({
        elementType: elementType,
        sourceElementId: value,
        value: value,
        elements: elements,
        sources: volumes,
        label: 'Your asset',
        limit: 1,
        id: name,
        name: name })
}}
```

Cole

Comment: Could you please explain the variables you used? The `value` property for example isn't needed, what value have your `elementType` and `elements` variables?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robin. The `elementType` is set to 'craft\elements\Asset' and the elements is an array containing a previously saved element (so null if new entry or not specified)

Comment: My guess would be that one of your parameters is incorrectly set. Without seeing their values it is tough to troubleshoot this further.